# proving a transpose times its original equals to $I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, proof-writing, matrix-equations

Let $P = [p_{ij}] \in \mathsf{M}_n (\{0,1\})$ (i.e., $p_{ij} = 0$ or $p_{ij} = 1)$ and suppose that 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} = 1,~i=1,\dots,n $$
and
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} = 1,~j=1,\dots,n. $$
Prove that $ P^\top P = I_n $.

I have no idea how to prove this. I always just considered  that $ P^\top P = I_n $ was true so I am coming up with no idea on how do do this.

so my question how do I prove this question?

I don't know if the title is accurate, but it you have a better one feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The product $PP^T$ has it's $(i,j)$th entry as $\sum_{k=1}^n P_{ik}P^T_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n P_{ik}P_{jk}$.

Now, note that there is precisely one $k_i$ for which $P_{ik_i} \neq 0$. If $j \neq i$, then naturally the product will be zero, since $k_i \neq k_j$, otherwise the vector containing $(i,j)$ and $(i,k)$ would have sum greater than $1$.

If $i = j$, then the above sum is clearly $1$, since the sum is just $\sum_{k=1}^n P_{ik}^2 = 1$.

Hence, the entries are $1$ if $i=j$, and $0$ otherwise. This is clearly a description of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} = 1,~i=1,\dots,n $$

means each column sums to $1$, since $P$ is a binary matrix, there is exactly one $1$ in each column.

and
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} = 1,~j=1,\dots,n. $$

means each row sum to $1$, similarly, there is exactly one $1$ in each row.

Hence $P$ is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Hence $P^T=P^{-1}$.

Comment: then would i have to prove that $P^{-1}P = I_{n}$ or can i say that that is just a fact

Comment: Isn't $P^{-1}$ defined to be the matrix that satisfy $P^{-1}P=PP^{-1}=I$?

Comment: yes it is. i was just wondering it i need to prove it , but apparently i can get by by just saying $PP^{−1}=I$, so thanks

Comment: I added a link to my post for readers who might not be familiar with permutation matrix.

Comment: how did you know that $P$ was a binary matrix, was it the $ P=[p_{ij}]∈M_n({0,1})$?

Comment: $P = [p_{ij}] \in \mathsf{M}_n (\{0,1\})$, yes, elements of $P$ take only value of $0$ and $1$.